# Concatenation of SQL query in PHP if statement

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to concatenate an SQL query through a PHP if statement like below:

```
$sqlProdPage = "SELECT DISTINCT productpts.ProductID,product.ProductTitle,productsubtype.ProductSubtype,producttype.ProductType,product.ProductPrice,product.ProdDiscount,product.ProductImage,
        product.ProductDescription,product.ProdFeatured,product.ProdQTY,product.ProdAddDesc 
        FROM productpts 
        INNER JOIN product ON productpts.ProductID=product.ProductID 
        INNER JOIN productsubtype ON productpts.ProductSubtypeID=productsubtype.ProductSubtypeID 
        INNER JOIN producttype ON productpts.ProductTypeID=producttype.ProductTypeID  
        WHERE product.Archive='0'";

$prodType_id=(($_POST['product'] != '')?sanitize($_POST['product']):'');
if(!empty($prodType_id)){
    $sqlProdPage.= " AND ProductTypeID='{$prodType_id}'";//echo $prodType_id;die();
}
```

From my troubleshooting which I carried out the problem is somewhere in the if statement in the concatenated SQL query

```
 $sqlProdPage.= " AND ProductTypeID='{$prodType_id}'"
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion on how to concatenate it?

[Results in chrome developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DXZ5.png)

But inline 37 i am having the below  error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\aresV2\search.php on line 37

**Line 36 and 37:**

```
$prodAvail = $db->query($sqlProdPage);
<?php while($product= mysqli_fetch_assoc($prodAvail)) : ?>
```

Comment: $sqlProdPage = $sqlProdPage." AND ProductTypeID='{$prodType_id}'"  try this

Comment: why do you have $prodType_id between brackets in  $sqlProdPage.= " AND ProductTypeID='{$prodType_id}'" ?

Comment: Looks OK to me. What was the resulting query as actually executed? Was $prodType_id valid? Did it have embedded `'` of its own?

Comment: posted results daren in image including error and code lines in question

Comment: The query is possibly not the problem then. It looks like you're mixing up two different ways of accessing your database, and that `$db->query()` method is returning TRUE or FALSE. You can't use that in `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`. Maybe there's a `$db->fetch()` or something (is it PDO?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `ProductTypeID` is defined in multiple tables, so it's not sure which it should use.

```
$sqlProdPage.= " AND productpts.ProductTypeID='{$prodType_id}'";
```

Should do the trick ( assuming it's from `productpts` table).

Comment: that was the solution to the problem Nigel. Thanks =]. Just had an surgery so I am still under the effect of anesthetic i guess hehe